# How to resolve H-10 App Crash Error on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, legacy-code

I have an old Rails application hosted on Heroku with PostgreSQL that I'm working towards getting onto Heroku-18 (I am aware of the support lifetime on 18).

I had to upgrade the rails application to get onto Heroku 18
Previous setup: Ruby 2.1.2 on Rails 4.1.6 / Heroku 14
Work in progress setup: Ruby 2.7.7 on Rails 5.2.2 / Heroku 18

Everything works locally but I'm having an app crash issue post Heroku deploy.

`heroku logs --tail`

`app\[web.1\]: Exiting heroku\[web.1\]: Process exited with status 1 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from starting to crashed heroku\[router\]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET`

I need to find the cause of the H10 error to get the app up and running on Heroku.
I reached out to their support but so far they have not been helpful.

Any ideas for tracking down what might be causing this?
Ideally I pull more logs than what I see here.

I do not have a procfile set up.

`heroku pg:info`

looks good

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

works

`heroku pg:psql`

connects successfully

`psql -h <hostname> -p 5432 -d <dbname> --username=<username> -w`

Connection timed out (from local machine, not heroku)

Visit website

> Application error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
> `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: Is that really all that is returned when running the logs tail?  It might help to see more of that return if there is more.

Comment: If you want an actual realistic test of the database connection use `heroku run rails db`. That will use the connection details from `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` and `database.yml`.

Comment: @RockwellRice https://pastebin.com/vxuDqA2s
Ideally I get general debugging tips but here's a more detailed log for your review

Comment: Ya looks like the issue was with puma, but you appear to have fixed by adding in the procfile anyways.  happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I updated my webserver to use Puma per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5

Then added a `Procfile`

with the following

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

and the puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup if defined?(DefaultRackup)
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

and the site is back up